# Pandas iloc boolean indexing

Tags: pandas, indexing

I am reading pandas doc
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing
there is a warning section that says "Warning
iloc supports two kinds of boolean indexing....." But the text and example only give one valid form: `df.iloc[s.values, 1]`. Another form is considered error: "`df.iloc[s, 1]` would raise ValueError"
So I am confused where is the 2nd boolean indexing that is supported by iloc? Maybe these guys call the invalid form as 'supported'?

Answer (score 0):

well according to the documentation:-

`df.iloc[s.values,1]` gives a valid output because `s.values` returns an `ndarray` of boolean values so this is the first form

`df[s].iloc[:,1]` also gives a valid output **"maybe"** its the second form.

who knows?

As this is not mentioned in the official documentation

.

.

but in the example given in documentation

I think they are reffering to `.loc accessor` i.e `df.loc[s, 'B']` as second form

because `df.loc[s, 'B']` is given as example in the documentation and also it is mentioned that:-

`df.iloc[s,1]` gives an invalid output i.e it raises error because s returns a `series` of boolean values and we can't use string indexing in `iloc` accessor.